# Shell, bash : grep the html tag in multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell

Shell, bash : grep the html tag in multiple lines

How do I grep from tr to /td in input.txt?

```
   <tr>
   <td>Answer</td>
```

My code is

```
 grep -o "<tr>.*</td>" input.txt > output.txt
```

But it returns nothing..

Comment: The dot in regex doesn't match a new line (and `grep` goes line-by-line anyway), so you would have to use `awk` or join the file lines together using `tr "\n" " " < input.txt | grep...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using a HTML parser, but for simple needs a range-based [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution may work

```
awk '/<tr>/,/<\/td\>/' input.txt
```